# Can I search a track on my phone?

Tags: zune, music, search

I can find any track easily by it's first letter, but sometimes I can remember only the other part (e.g. `Shooter` in the `Super Sharp Shooter`). Zune Software has a search box (in full text mode), but I can't find one on my phone.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is something I know many have wished for but it can't be done.

Post/support the feature request at the [User Voice site](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions)

Comment: Here it is: http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2286437-better-search-options-for-locally-stored-music-on-

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for now. Hope to see this in a future OS update

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Find My Music](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/find-my-music/c3055b87-749a-41c5-bd99-81f9f4766594)

Answer (score 0):

There are apps that provide search. For example, [Instant Music Search Pro](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=a0ca85f5-bee8-449c-9bc3-f1ff0b5132fb) provides some of the missing search functionality that you are looking for.